# What is 2msGtG (0.5ms)?

Tags: display, gaming

Planning to buy a gaming monitor ACER NITRO XV240YP, box printed it is 0.5ms , but when I do some research online, it show 2msGtG (0.5ms). And I have google search on it, cant found a best explanation for it. Can anyone explain for me? Just want to confirm it can really run like as low as 1ms? because I did'nt expect IPS to run 0.5ms

Comment: From what I gather G2G is “grey to grey” response time measurement. Cannot find much more than this page that explains what it is to a similar question: https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/2ms-gtg-whats-this-mean.260190/#post-2680698

Comment: same bro i cannot find more related information. I just want to make sure its real can hit 1ms did anyone make a test?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between gtg and btw response time estimation of displays](https://superuser.com/questions/738414/difference-between-gtg-and-btw-response-time-estimation-of-displays)